# use a tag to submit form to other page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, hyperlink

I wanted to use an a tag to submit a form to another page. However, when I do this, and use href="" to go to this page, the form seems not to be submitted. It looks like this:

```
<form id="SomeForm" action="SomePage.php" method="GET">
    <!--Here are some inputs-->
</form>

<a href="SomePage.php" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('SomeForm').submit();">
    The link to click on
</a>
```

When clicking on this link, The browser goes to the right page, but the submitted form is gone. I used a javascript code line to make one big URL for the page so it looked like it was submitted, but I would also like to be able to submit forms with method="POST". It workes if it is on the same page and href="#", but otherwise it doesn't. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to put the href attribute to "#" like this? : <a href="#". In this way it will add to your URL a "#" but, at the same time, it will submit your form. Also, you can use a well styled <span> to submit the form (instead of the <a> tag) but in this way you should be able to solve your problem

Comment: Just did, It worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('SomeForm').submit();">
    The link to click on
</a>
```

alternative:

```
<div id="someID" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('SomeForm').submit();">
    <!-- Click anywhere in this div to submit the form -->
</div>
```

Comment: I used the link tag so the cursor would change into the pointerhand, but I just found out ther way to use that without the link tag, with the alternative you gave. it works both ways.

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)